# Prove that $E$ is a connected subset of $R^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $E\subset R^2$ be the collection of all points such that at least one of their coordinates is rational,  Prove that $E$ is a connected.

Comment: Even though the question has been answered, please show some work next time =]

Answer (score 1):

Each point connects to the x or y axis which connects to the origin, so the collection is connected.

Edit: here is a related question discussing [connectedness vs. path connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118097) and methods of proof

Comment: Aren't you thinking of path connected? Note however, that path connected does indeed imply connected.

Comment: path connected implies connected

Comment: @comptuerbro Could you please elaborate a bit more? I still don't understand how you proved that E is path connected.